# Undefined values of nitrogen dioxide in time series chart (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

I am not able to see the values for NO2 in the time series. In the figure, `tropspheric_No2_coloumn_density` displays the value zero.

How to display the correct value?

[image]

```
var geom Table users/shapefile
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(geom)
  .filterDate('2019-03-01', '2019-08-31');

function tabulate(i){
  return geom.map(function (f){
    var r = i.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      geometry: f.geometry(), 
      scale: 3,
      bestEffort:true,
      maxPixels:1e9});
return ee.Feature(null, {
  name: f.get('OBJECTID'),
  index: i.get('system:time_start'),
}).setMulti(r);
  });}

var resultstable = collection.map(tabulate).flatten();

print(ui.Chart.image.series(collection, geom));
```